# I need to write a haskell function which duplicates every occurrence of a character in a string, both given by the user.

Tags: function, haskell, duplicates

So far, this is what I have. I know it has something to do with the function itself since I have Char -> String -> String, but I need it to be input from the user, so IO. I am not really sure how to do this.

```
dup :: Char -> String -> String
dup c [] = []
dup c (x:xs)
  | c == x    =  x:x:dup c xs
  | otherwise =  x:dup c xs

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a sentence."
  sentence <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter a single letter that is in your sentence, to duplicate."
  letter <- getLine
  let x = dup 'letter''sentence'
   putStrLn x
```

Comment: `dup y = (>>= \x -> x : [x | x == y])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems, so I'll go in order. First, syntax:

1. You don't want the final `putStrLn x` do be on a different indentation level from the rest of the content of your `do` block.
2. You don't want to surround `letter` and `sentence` by single-quotes in your function call.

If we change these and try to compile, we get the following error:

> • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
>         Expected type: Char
>           Actual type: String
>       • In the first argument of ‘dup’, namely ‘letter’
>         In the expression: dup letter sentence
>         In an equation for ‘x’: x = dup letter sentence

The problem is that the type of `letter` is `String`, while we need it to be `Char`. One way to fix this would be to use the `getChar` function instead, which has type `IO Char` rather than `IO String`:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a sentence."
  sentence <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter a single letter that is in your sentence, to duplicate."
  letter <- getChar
  let x = dup letter sentence
  putStrLn $ '\n' : x
```

I've added the line break character `'\n'` before the `x` so that output is printed on a new line.

Usage:

```
ghci>> main
Enter a sentence.
hi
Enter a single letter that is in your sentence, to duplicate.
h
hhi
```

Answer (score 3):

So close.  Where `getLine` gives a `String`, or `[Char]`, you just want a `Char`.  You can do this:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a sentence."
  sentence <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter a single letter that is in your sentence, to duplicate."
  -- Get first character only
  letter:_ <- getLine
  let x = dup letter sentence
  putStrLn x
```

There are some caveats to this, since the pattern matching could fail, but it will work, and it is quite close to what you wrote.

Comment: Is there any reason this would be preferred over `getChar`? Wouldn't it be better to fail if improper string input is given, rather than giving the appearance that the entire string is being processed?

Comment: `getChar` doesn't consume a newline, which makes it not very friendly for users.

Comment: Fair enough; I added the a newline explicitly in my answer. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To be clear: **consume** a newline.  This is different from emitting a newline.  When users type input into a command-line program, they typically expect that you can type an input, and then press enter when they are done typing it.  You can then do input validation later.

Comment: The reason you emit a newline is a quirk of the terminal, it only works that way because echo is enabled.  If your terminal is set not to echo, or if standard input and output are different streams, then you'll get an extra newline.  Not that those are reasonable things to expect here, though.